# Global options as function local variables

Tags: vimscript, functions, variables

I'm asking about [this](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html#implicit-returning) code snippet:

```
:function TextwidthIsTooWide()
:  if &l:textwidth ># 80
:    return 1
:  endif
:endfunction
```

This is what [vim-help](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#local-variable) says on the `l` (local) prefix:

> Inside functions local variables are accessed without prepending
> anything. But you can also prepend "l:" if you like.  However, without
> prepending "l:" you may run into reserved variable names.  For example
> "count".  By itself it refers to "v:count".  Using "l:count" you can
> have a local variable with the same name.

Based on this, I would expect `l:textwidth` to be something like `0` or `undefined`, instead of taking the value of the global (?) `textwidth` option. (C.f. `v:count` vs `l:count` in the documentation.)

**Question:** Why does it take on the value of the option, even though it is local?

I do realize it has the `&` symbol prefixed, which refers to the option, so maybe it overrides local.

**Question:** In that case (i.e., if `&` overrides `local`), what is the point of making the variable local?

I tried the following change (only difference: remove `l:` prefix) and it seems to work too (even with `setlocal` -- of course I realize this is a different kind of "localness" compared to function-local variables)

```
:function! TextwidthIsTooWide()
:  if &textwidth ># 80
:    return 1
:  endif
:endfunction
```

```
:set textwidth=79
:echo TextwidthIsTooWide()
0


:set textwidth=81
:echo TextwidthIsTooWide()
1

:setlocal textwidth=79
:echo TextwidthIsTooWide()
0


:setlocal textwidth=81
:echo TextwidthIsTooWide()
1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is all told under `:h :let-option`, but, to put it short, `let &option="value"` is the same as `set option=value`, `let &l:option="value"` is the same as `setlocal option=value`, and `let &g:option="value"` is `setglobal option=value`.

So your last point is actually about the difference between `set/setglobal/setlocal` commands. Again, putting it short, `set option=value` for a buffer-local option (such as `:h 'textwidth'`) is the same as executing `setglobal option=value` and `setlocal option=value` at the same time.

Also, it should be noted that when reading from a buffer-local option using `&`-notation, "a local" value is returned, so `if &tw > 80` and `if &l:tw > 80` are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Side note: a global-local option may not have been overridden at the local level. This means we could work either with a global setting or one that has been overridden in a some buffers.

Usually users don't need much to bother with that. Even in most plugins, we can simply test `&{optionname}` that will return the most specialized value.

The troubles come when a plugin needs to momentarily change a global-local option and restore its value afterward. In that case it's better to determine whether it was overridden for the current buffer or not. And it's not that trivial to do... See my [`lh#option#is_set_locally()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/693f67011cb8a959875524502661442412cba60a/autoload/lh/option.vim#L286)

BTW, as you could see, I never use `l:` when I have the choice. I don't see the point to use Hungarian notation in vimscript while I do not in other languages.

Comment: It’s *Hungarian*, and I believe it to be misunderstood (but I’m not here to argue the point :) )

Comment: Oh indeed thanks. I didn't want to argue about its various forms either ^^'